# Excel VBA: CommandButton click time

Tags: excel, button, time, vba

I wonder if there is a way to speed up time of clicking `CommandButtons`?

Thing is when I use my `UserForm` in many cases I click "next" button multiple times, however button does not react as fast as I click. So there are times I clicked 3 times and "next" button took only to second record rather then forth.

Edit:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

TextBox1 = TextBox1 + 1

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

TextBox1 = TextBox1 - 1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

TextBox1.Value = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: do you execute any code before showing the buttons? maybe the code is running in some tight loop causing the button not to react?

Comment: Hm... not sure if that's the issue. When I click "enter" button on my keyboard to click "next" it runs smoothly. Thing happens only when clicking button with mouse.

Comment: when you hit "enter" the button is already selected and has the focus, when you click the button it first receives the focus before being clicked .. maybe that causes the difference?

Comment: Do you think this may be the cause of delay? Is there a way to speed it up then?

Comment: depends on your code .. please post the code involved .. if it's possible try to create a small test project which has the same behaviour and post that code .. or copy your current project and remove all irrelvant code to make it as small as possible and issolate the problem

Comment: I created simplest userform and it looks like it is some kind of common issue. Without any code given it still changes value really slow and does not respond to all of my clicks.

Comment: There will always be a bit of a delay otherwise there would be no way to differentiate between a double-click and a click.

Comment: Right... haven't thought about it. Guess that is anwser to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser credits goes to Rory who pointed out `DblClick Event`. So having that in mind it is easy to to change code to work better. All we need to do is add `Dblclick Event` and work it as minus / plus 2 so it looks like working faster then before.

In my case I needed to add some restriction with numbers below zero but main idea is wrote below :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_DblClick()

TextBox1 = TextBox1 + 2

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_DblClick()

TextBox1 = TextBox1 - 2

End Sub
```